# How to use SAGA_CMD for batch processing?

Tags: lidar, saga, batch, geotiff-tiff, las

I am trying to use SAGA to triangulate a set of .las files I have. I have tiled them using LAStools, since the single file was too big for my computer to handle. I wonder, can I use the saga_cmd grid_gridding "Triangulation" for multiple files, or do I have to process each individually? And I want tif files based on the Z-value, where do I specify the Z value? Is it the -FIELD Attribute?

I have found very little information about the cli scripting of SAGA, are there any book available on the subject?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `saga_cmd grid_gridding Triangulation` in a batch file, just like all the other modules. If you want the result files based on the Z-value, you have to specify in the `-FIELD` attribute.

For a quick example of batch file in SAGA, just type:

```
saga_cmd -b
```

All you have to know about the use of SAGA command line (and not only) is described in ["Automation of Workflows with SAGA - Command line scripting in a nutshell"](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/sourceforge/s/project/sa/saga-gis/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/Command_Line_Scripting/scripting_saga.pdf) of Volker Wichmann. For instance, here you will find:

- SAGA | CMD Scripting Example Windows – batch_example.bat (slide 14)
- SAGA | CMD Scripting Example GNU/Linux – bash_example.sh (slide 15)